# Matching arrays returned from sequelize with Jest

Tags: arrays, node.js, jestjs, sequelize.js

I'm testing a Node.js application, in which addresses are stored in a Postgresql database using Sequelize. In order to test the 'getAll()' function, I wrote a test that does the following (see below): 
    1. create two addresses, and store them ('create' function of Sequelize)
    2. call the getAll() function
    3. (try to) assert that the returned array contains the created addresses, using expect.arrayContaining()

I tested the same setup without Sequelize in between (adding numbers/objects to an array and match a subset in the same way I did here), which works fine.

```
 it("Should get all addresses", async () => {
     const address_1 = await Address.create({
         street: VALID_STREET,
         number: VALID_NUMBER,
         city: VALID_CITY,
         country: VALID_COUNTRY
     });
     const address_2 = await Address.create({
         street: "street 2",
         number: "2",
         city: "City 2",
         country: "Country 2"
     });

     const allAddresses = await controller._getAll();
     expect(allAddresses).toEqual(
         expect.arrayContaining([address_1, address_2])
     );
 });
```

I expected the test to succeed, but it fails, giving me this errormessage that contains the two exact same arrays, except for the 'ArrayContaining' part.

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: ArrayContaining [{"city": "A city", "country": "Belgium", "createdAt": 2019-08-21T14:05:23.063Z, "fullAddress": "valid street 123 A, A city, Belgium", "id": 296, "number": "123 A", "postalCode": null, "street": "valid street", "updatedAt": 2019-08-21T14:05:23.063Z}, {"city": "City 2", "country": "Country 2", "createdAt": 2019-08-21T14:05:23.066Z, "fullAddress": "street 2 2, City 2, Country 2", "id": 297, "number": "2", "postalCode": null, "street": "street 2", "updatedAt": 2019-08-21T14:05:23.066Z}]
    Received: [{"city": "A city", "country": "Belgium", "createdAt": 2019-08-21T14:05:23.063Z, "fullAddress": "valid street 123 A, A city, Belgium", "id": 296, "number": "123 A", "postalCode": null, "street": "valid street", "updatedAt": 2019-08-21T14:05:23.063Z}, {"city": "City 2", "country": "Country 2", "createdAt": 2019-08-21T14:05:23.066Z, "fullAddress": "street 2 2, City 2, Country 2", "id": 297, "number": "2", "postalCode": null, "street": "street 2", "updatedAt": 2019-08-21T14:05:23.066Z}]
```

So, does anyone know how to fix this? Is this a Sequelize problem, or am I missing something here?

EDIT:
For people running into the same problem, I do have a workaround, which is to use the array.some() function, but this seems to be too verbose and I feel like the expect.arrayContaining() function should be used for this purpose.

```
expect(
    allAddresses.some(address => {
        address.id === address_2.id &&
        address.street === address_2.street &&
        address.number === address_2.number &&
        address.city === address_2.city &&
        address.country === address_2.country;
    })
);
```

Comment: Mind sharing what `controller._getAll()` does?

Comment: And I also asked myself why you use `arrayContaining` instead of `expect(allAddresses).toEqual([address_1, address_2])` here. You add two elements and you want to have these two elements from `_getAll`, don't you?

Comment: Of course; the _getAll() method is actually just a wrapper around the findAll() function of sequelize, that handles errors in an application specific way, but does not alter the returned data. 
As for your second question: I tried that, but got this error: ```Compared values serialize to the same structure.
    Printing internal object structure without calling `toJSON` instead```. I then tried to convert them to JSON, but that did't work either (same result as the error in the original question, except with all  quotes escaped)

Comment: Are you using `raw: true` in your `findAll` query?
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-usage.html#raw-queries

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that, but doesn't fix it.

Comment: So, to me it seems that from `create` you get a `Model` instance and you try to compare it with the raw output of the `findAll` method (I assume plain objects). Could you, just to falsify this assumption, manually assing the properties of the created entities to plain javascript objects? Maybe via `Object.assign(address_2_pojo, address_2)` (same for address_1) and compare with this?

Comment: Ok, I locally reproduced it and I think I got it. `create` returns a model. It has a property called `dataValues` containing only the values (the model has lots of other properties and methods). If you run `findAll` with `raw: true` and compare to an array with `[address_1.dataValues, address_2.dataValues]` it should work (I'd suggest `toEqual` for it).

Comment: Ok for some strange reason the `createdAt` date has a different format in what is returned by `create` vs. in what is returned from `findAll`. I'll formulate a proper answer bcs. I need the formatting to display this correctly. Expect my answer in ~10 minutes.

Comment: Here's an explanation and a fix for the date format: https://www.nonamez.name/en/post/how_to_handle_mysql_date_and_time_formats_in_sequelize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not a good idea to compare the whole Models (lot's of stuff you don't care about in there). Try to compare the `dataValues` instead. Make sure you don't use `raw: true` in your `findAll` call because then you don't have the `dataValues` property.

```js
const allAddresses = await controller._getAll();
const addressesPlain = allAddresses.map(address => address.dataValues);

expect([address_1.dataValues, address_2.dataValues]).toEqual(addressesPlain);
```

If you're interested in the small test case I wrote: https://pastr.io/view/QKNmua

Comment: This fixes it! Thanks for the time and work you put in! Additionally, I found that in a case where more than 2 addresses are in the database, using 'toEqual' would fail (because of extra addresses being returned, obviously), but this also works with `expect.arrayContaining()`, as I was originally trying! 
`expect(addressesPlain).toEqual(
        expect.arrayContaining([address_1.dataValues, address_2.dataValues])
    );`

Comment: You're welcome. Concerning the `toEqual`: As you have everything under control in your test, you should know the number of items when your assertion is running. You insert two, you expect two. You should not start this test with other items in the database. And another thing: I'm not sure what you want to test, but what you're testing here is basically "if I add two items with sequelize.js, and I try to retrieve them with sequelize.js, are they still two and have the same content?". Maybe you go back a bit and think about how you can test your app, not the library you use. :-)

Comment: True. I did condense this test to just show the problem though, but I might indeed be testing too much! I am, for example, testing if constraints in the database work as I expect (although that is more to prevent them from being changed and breaking something than to actually test them), what do you think of this? In other words, how far should I go in testing what gets inserted (and how) and comes back?

Comment: Speaking about unit tests, I'd completely mock away the database. I'd make sure that I would send the proper data and if I receive data I'd make sure that I a) expect wrong data but can recover / work with / log b) process the data as specified. Making sure that the database does whatever you expect it to do can be done in integration tests. You might want to read up on 'test pyramid', 'integration tests' and 'unit tests'. Also check the mocking part of the Jest documentation (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions). Have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it using arrayContaining matcher, not any better just a little more explicit IMO:

```
const allAddresses = await controller._getAll();
const addressesPlain = allAddresses.map(address => address.dataValues);

expect(addressesPlain).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining([address_1.dataValues, address_2.dataValues]);
```

I've found that searching for a single item in an array to be a little confusing using jest's matchers as well so for just checking that a single object is in an array this has been useful:

```
expect(addressesPlain).toContainEqual(address_1.dataValues)
```

toContainEqual, as their docs state, "recursively checks the equality of all fields, rather than checking for object identity." while toContain does check for objectIdentity which will fail with the above check.